# Rails skip individual validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

A user in my app can be a normal user or an admin. This is just a column in the database.

Admin has more privileges, it can for example update other users data through the Admin panel. Regular user can only update their own data through their profile page.

The admin panel and user profile page use different rails controllers(their own). 
It's possible to change any users data through the admin controller.

This is my validate on update method for model user:

```
  validate on: :update do
    validate_name
    validate_age
    validate_blood_type
  end
```

Lets say when an admin updates a user through the Admin panel, I want to skip validate_age:

```
if update(age: new_age)
   render json: {message: "Age updated"}, status: :ok
end
```

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validations are thought to check data (formats, boundaries, dependencies), not permissions. AFAIK, the validate statement does not allow you to pass further parameters (like the currently active user).

Different ways around this:

- Put the "updating" user as an own field into the model (like an "updated_by" ref to your user table) and make a custom validator that checks if the updated_by user has admin privileges. You should carefully consider the impacts: The updated_by user must always be set correct, you got more references, more management overhead etc.
- Define a separate check function in the model, like

model.rb:

```
def valid_age?(current_user)
  self.age < min_age ? (current_user == admin_user) : true
end
```

and call this check from your controller every time you update data

- Put this part of the validation completely into the controller.

Comment: All these ways would work but require  relatively large number of changes in different places in the app. I also found this solution: https://richonrails.com/articles/skipping-validations-in-ruby-on-rails. Are there any issues that you can think of with the solution given in the "Skipping Individual Validations" section? If so, then I am going to implement the updated_by method, because it seems the neatest way.

Comment: `current_user` is not available within the model, sorry!

Comment: @MeesterPatat: I'm not very deep into the internals of rails. On the first glance, I would take a careful try with it. I could imagine, that overriding update and save can have unwanted effects (especially as the base implementation might change during further rails versions). Additionally, I do not know if update/save are the ultimate endpoints for all writing operations: What about "save!" and so on. Might work, might now. But worth a try.

Comment: @Steve Turczyn: current_user in my example is a parameter to a new validation check.

Comment: Ah, right, sorry, I missed that it was a passed parameter.  Not keen on this solution... I'd rather have your first solution... updated_by could just be an attr_accessor, no need to save.  But cool, and sorry again for misreading.

Comment: Steve Turczyn: attr_accessor seems a good idea. There's no need to keep it persistent for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding `role` column into user, and role can be `admin`, `developer`, 'company_user' or anything.

then you can check role before validation is called, please check below code.

```
validate on: :update do
    validate_name
    validate_age unless self.role == 'admin'
    validate_blood_type
end
```

Comment: I already have user roles, but admin can update other users, your solution only works if admin updates itself.

Comment: so what you want to do? I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
validate on: :update do
  validate_name
  validate_age unless admin_update
  validate_blood_type
end

def admin_update
  updated_by == User::getAdminId()
end
```

Update:
Why?: When the checking condition changes, just change in admin_update function.
And, admin_update is separated, so it's easy to test (unit or functional...).

Comment: I'll have to implement the updated_by method myself right?

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: @MeesterPatat: Yes. And in case the condition changes, you just change in admin_update only. It is separated to easy to test.